# Axios & TypeScript - no error when typed POST returns different property names

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

Type checking does not seem to be happening the way I expected it would in my front-end code.

I'm using Axios in a React app to fetch data from my backend API.  I had a situation where JSON serialization was not working correctly in the backend, but no errors were thrown in the front end alerting me to the mismatch of property names.  Instead, it seems like the type is being ignored and the inccorrectly structured data is returned anyway.

I want to understand why the code below does not throw an error, and if there is a way to refactor it so type mismatches are actually caught, since this is supposed to be one of the benefits of TypeScript.

Type being used in the React app:

```
export type Article = {
    id: string;
    date: string;
    trans_title: string;
    article_text: string;
}
```

API call in the React app:

```
const resp = await axios.post<Article[]>('/api/articles', filterObj, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (await this.getAccessToken()).token
    }
});
```

If I inspect `resp.data`, I find an array of objects with the following properties:

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", 
    "date": "2024-01-15T01:00:00.000000Z", 
    "transTitle": "Title text", 
    "articleText": "Article text"
}
```

As you can see, the API is returning objects with properties `transTitle` instead of the type's `trans_title` and `articleText` instead of the type's `article_text`.

Since my API is returning different property names than the type I'm defining for the Axios post, I expected a compile time exception or intellisense error.  In my case, React needs to render some of the properties as values in the UI.  So the property names matter.  However there is no error thrown.  It just ignores the Article type's properties and returns the data anyway.

Is there a way to make Axios enforce the actual property names in a typed post?

Comment: TypeScript only performs static type checks and after compiling it's plain JS. Use some library like ajv or zod for schema validation.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  I guess when I start thinking in terms of types my brain switches to back-end development, which I mostly due with C#, so I end up expecting things that can't really happen with code running in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript only checks types at compilation time, not at runtime. By passing the type definition to the axios generic argument (`axios.post<Article[]>`), you are asserting that you expect the API to return an `Article` array, so you'll get typing for the result. But Axios doesn't (and can't, given the nature of TypeScript) do anything with that generic type at runtime to validate that the response is actually what you asserted.

You'll want to adjust your types to describe what you are getting in reality from the API (assuming that is correct - otherwise, modify the API behavior to match the types). If you want runtime checking, you could write a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), like this:

```
function isArticle(thing: any): thing is Article {
  return (
    // It's up to you to implement this correctly.
    typeof thing === "object" &&
    thing !== null &&
    typeof thing.id === "string" &&
    typeof thing.date === "string" &&
    typeof thing.trans_title === "string" &&
    typeof thing.article_text === "string"
  );
}
```

Also, as brc-dd mentioned in the comments, there are libraries that aim to do this type of runtime validation for you in a structured way. He mentioned [ajv](https://ajv.js.org/guide/typescript.html) or [zod](https://zod.dev/). If the API has a swagger definition, you could also use [OpenAPI Typescript](https://openapi-ts.pages.dev/) to generate a strongly-typed client that conforms to the API.

Answer (score 0):

As notes, Typescript only provides type-checking while developing. It will not enforce types in production.

Zod is a beautiful library built with typescript to do exactly this: https://zod.dev/

You can do something like this:

```
 import z from "zod"
 export const ArticleSchema = zod.object({
    id: z.string(),
    date: z.string()
    trans_title: z.string(),
    article_text: z.string(),
});

export type Article = z.typeof<typeof ArticleSchema>

// In your axios call
const resp = await axios.post<Article[]>('/api/articles', filterObj, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + (await this.getAccessToken()).token
    }
});

// This will throw an error if it is not correctly parsed, you you would prefer to NOT have an error thrown, but decide what to do if not an article on your own, use .safeParse
const article = ArticleSchema.parse(resp.body);
```